# How do I dynamically create a zip file using PHP on Linux?

Tags: php, zip

I need my PHP script (running on a Linux server) to dynamically create a downloadable zip. Presently my script is working locally on my Windows server, but not on Linux.

If anyone can help me out with sample script, your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: It's Linux

Comment: why dont you post your script along with any error messages you get when you run it in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

See the [`ZipArchive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class. There are some code examples, e.g. under `ZipArchive::addFile`.